# How can I view Google Chrome DNS cache on MacOs Mojave?

Tags: google-chrome, dns, incognito-mode

I'm wondering if there is a terminal command that allows me to view my google chrome DNS cache on Mac.
Thanks

Comment: Now, the DNS page in `chrome://net-internals/#dns` can only clean, not to show all of the cache items. My version is `72.0.3626.119`.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same exact problem. Chrome is resolving a URL to the wrong IP, all other browsers resolve to the correct one. Upon inspecting the net-internals menu it just gives me the option to clear cache. There doesn't appear to be any direct way to see it.

What I did instead is I allowed the website to resolve to the wrong IP, then accessed the developer menu (F12 on Windows), clicked on Network, chose one of the loaded images and clicked the 'Headers' tab. under General -> Remote Address it showed me which cloudflare proxy IP the something.com address was resolved.

Comment: I was struggling with the fact that only Chrome would not properly refresh my dns cache. I made an NGINX mistake which did a redirect, which was fixed later. I kept smashing the chrome://net-internals/#dns button, but nothing worked. Until I reserved the log on the network tab and suddenly, it worked... No clue why, maybe the DNS cache even expired at the exact time. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯